# How can I redim my array for the next file I open up?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an script built to go into a file in a `dir` and form an array based off of the data.

How would I print this:

```
Dim k As Long, x As Long, j As Long ' counters
Dim varArray() As Variant
ReDim varArray(1 To 13, 1 To 1)

ReDim varArray(1 To UBound(varArray, 1), 1 To 1)

        For j = 1 To .UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
            If .Cells(j, 1) <> "" Then
                x = x + 1
                ReDim Preserve varArray(1 To UBound(varArray, 1), 1 To x)
                    For k = 1 To UBound(varArray, 1)
                        varArray(k, x) = .Cells(j, k)
                    Next
            End If
        Next
```

This builds the array, but I now need it printed to the sheet, so I wrote this:

```
    With Workbooks("master.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet2")


            For j = 2 To UBound(varArray, 2)
                For k = 1 To UBound(varArray, 1)
                    ActiveSheet.Cells(j, k) = varArray(k, j)
                Next
            Next

    End With
```

This works, but now I need to clear out the array after it has printed with a Redim, but this:

```
ReDim varArray(1 To UBound(varArray, 1), 1 To 1)
```

doesn't clear it after I place it after the last `end with`

Here's the whole script for the sake of the bigger picture:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Stuff()

Dim k As Long, x As Long, j As Long ' counters
Dim varArray() As Variant
ReDim varArray(1 To 13, 1 To 1)

Dim MyFile As String


MyFile = Dir("M:\Merge Files\")

If Len(MyFile) <> 0 Then




    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

        ReDim varArray(1 To UBound(varArray, 1), 1 To 1)

            For j = 1 To .UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
                If .Cells(j, 1) <> "" Then
                    x = x + 1
                    ReDim Preserve varArray(1 To UBound(varArray, 1), 1 To x)
                        For k = 1 To UBound(varArray, 1)
                            varArray(k, x) = .Cells(j, k)
                        Next
                End If
            Next
    End With

        With Workbooks("master.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet2")


                For j = 2 To UBound(varArray, 2)
                    For k = 1 To UBound(varArray, 1)
                        ActiveSheet.Cells(j, k) = varArray(k, j)
                    Next
                Next

        End With

ReDim varArray(1 To UBound(varArray, 1), 1 To 1)

End If


End Sub
```

Comment: You already know the maximum elements (`.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1`). Why not size the array for the maximum and then keep track of the indices that actually contain data. The repeated reallocations aren't really necessary.

Comment: Can you just use `Erase varArray` after you've printed to the sheet?

Comment: Those are the maximum elements for one workbook. I have a lot more in the directory, so I guess I don't understand what you're commenting on. I have an array built off workbook 1, I print it to master.xlsm, I need to clear the array, and then move onto workbook 2 so I can print to master.xlsx and so forth.

Comment: @nicklanta Try `Erase` to just empty/clear it :)

Comment: @dwirony that's what I would need to do, but where would I put that so it doesn't erase it before it prints to the master.xlsm wb?

Comment: @nicklanta Replace `ReDim varArray(1 To UBound(varArray, 1), 1 To 1)` with `Erase varArray` at the end.

Comment: @dwirony ok, so it worked and erased my varArray, perfect. One problem popped up, but it's dealing with the files in the directory. It's just cycling back to the same file and creating the array all over again. Is there some sort of For/Next I should substitute in place of the the Do While/Loop part?

Comment: @nicklanta Try adding `MyFile = Dir` after the `Erase` line.

Comment: @dwirony quick question, what if I wanted to just keep adding to my array? the above script does a great job of opening the first file and forming an array/printing to the master sheet, but what could I add after the final `end with` in order to have it preserve that data and then tack on the next file data until I've looped through the whole folder?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182511/discussion-between-dwirony-and-nick-lanta).

Comment: @dwirony sent you the details